# CSS display:table-cell content in wrong position

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a simple structure of div behaving as tables that is one row with two columns, one with 80% and the other with the remaining space. In fact, the first column is two 80% columns, but I only show one at once hidding the other with `display: none`:

```js
$("#change").on("click", function() {
 $(".table .container")
   .toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 185px;
  padding: 10x 30px;
}

.table div {
  display: table-cell;
  color: #fff
}

.table .container {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #ccc
}
.table .hidden {
  display: none
}

.table .side-bar {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table">
  <div class="container">1</div>
  <div class="container hidden">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">3</div>
</div>
<button id="change">
Toggle column
</button>
```

It works well as pure html and css. But these two columns hold a widget each. The second column haves a listView widget, which creates a bunch of divs inside it. Those divs inflicts in the third column content. It pulls the content down:

```js
$("#change").on("click", function() {
 $(".table .container")
   .toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 185px;
  padding: 10x 30px;
}

.table div {
  display: table-cell;
  color: #fff
}

.table .container {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #ccc
}
.table .hidden {
  display: none
}

.table .side-bar {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0 20px
}
.table .container .insider {
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  width: 80px; 
  height: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="container">1</div>
  <div class="container hidden">
    <div class="insider">2</div>
    <div class="insider">2</div>
    <div class="insider">2</div>
    <div class="insider">2</div>
    <div class="insider">2</div>
    <div class="insider">2</div>
    <div class="insider">2</div>
    <div class="insider">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">3</div>
</div>
<button id="change">
Toggle container
</button>
```

Check how the third column's(the black one) content is pulled down when you toggle the state of the columns. The divs inside it(with `.insider` class) are generated by the javascript widget, so I have no control over it style. I think it is possible to change it, but I prefer not to do so.

How can I change the columns without changing the third column's content position?

Comment: As for me, it will be better if you keep first column visible always and move both containers inside it and toggle each one.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman that's a nice idea actually. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following css:

```
.table div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: You're totally right!! So easy. I have tried that but on the third column only and it didn't worked. Thank you!